# Django - how do I filter or exclude by two identical fields?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

We are using Django for our website. I have a query for model `User` and I want to exclude users which have two identical fields - in this case `id` and `username`. So if the `id`==`username`, I want to exclude them. How do I do it?

The query looks like:

```py
users = User.objects.filter(...)
```

And I want to add `.exclude(...)` where the `id` and `username` fields are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to a field with an [**`F`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F), so:

```
from django.db.models import F

users = User.objects.exclude(id=F('username'))
```